Dockerized Microfrontend Shows White Screen in Production, No Errors in Console
I'm working on dockerizing and deploying a microfrontend (MFE) application. The development Dockerfile works fine and loads the app as expected. However, when I switch to the production Dockerfile, the app only shows a white screen with no errors in the console.
Here are some key details:

Development Dockerfile: Works fine, the app loads without any issues.
Production Dockerfile: Builds the app using Webpack and serves it with Nginx, but results in a white screen.
Webpack Configuration: I suspect that Webpack might not be correctly building the static files or injecting them into the HTML.

Webpack Configurations
webpack.common.js:
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config({ path: "./.env" });

const isProduction = process.env.REACT_IS_PRODUCTION === "true";

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "ts-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          isProduction ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|webp)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[contenthash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "assets",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public/index.html"),
      inject: "body",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
    }),
  ],
};


webpack.prod.js:
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common");
const packageJson = require("../package.json");
const path = require("path");

const prodConfig = {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    publicPath: "/component/",
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "component",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./Button": "./src/components/button/Button",
        "./Input": "./src/components/input/Input",
        "./Tabs": "./src/components/tab/Tabs",
        "./Tab": "./src/components/tab/Tab",
        "./Table": "./src/components/table/Table",
        "./ProgressBar": "./src/components/progress/ProgressBar",
        "./Card": "./src/components/card/Card",
        "./DoughnutChart": "./src/components/charts/DoughnutChart",
        "./Modal": "./src/components/modal/Modal",
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, prodConfig);

Docker Files
Dockerfile.Prod:
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/component


nginx.conf:
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /component/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/component/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /component/index.html;
        }

        location / {
            return 404;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}


When I build and run the production Docker image, I get a blank white screen in the browser. There are no errors in the console, and the network tab shows that the files are being served correctly. My suspicion is that Webpack isn't building the static files correctly or that they are not being injected into the HTML properly.
What I've Tried

Verified the Webpack build outputs.
Checked the Nginx configuration to ensure it serves the files correctly.
Ran the Docker image with serve instead of Nginx, but the result is the same.

What could be causing the white screen in production, and how can I debug this issue further? Are there any common pitfalls with Webpack and Nginx serving that might cause this?
